# Different non-linear dag execution

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

have any sample like this architecture not lineal ?

dag1->dag11
|
dag2->dag21->dag22
|
dag3->dag31
|
dag4

dag1/2/3/4 are lineal an depen_on true

Thanks !!!
Luis

Comment: Sorry all are "task" in a principal dag

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.